# A single-variable continuous function that is irrational if and only if its argument is rational

Tags: real-analysis

I wonder if it is possible to construct a continuous $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that for each $x \in \mathbb R$, $f(x)$ is irrational if and only if $x$ is rational?

**my attempt**

Sadly, I pretty much don't know where to start with this one. Intuitively I feel this is impossible. But I just can't see what could go wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  show that a continuous, non-constant function on the reals must take uncountably many irrational values.

Comment: @lulu Ah! Of course! Thanks a lot!

Comment: However, if you allow the function to be discontinuous at rational points, it can be done (just multiply the popcorn function by an irrational constant).

Comment: @tomasz Isn't Thomae's function nowhere continuous?

Comment: @michaelshiyu: No. It is continuous at all irrational numbers.

Comment: @tomasz Ah yes! Sorry I was too hasty in saying that. Thanks!

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367856), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877475), and most recently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877504).

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Sorry for having missed those existing questions. I swear I looked this question up in math SE really hard before posting it (although obviously not hard enough).

Comment: @michaelshiyu You are forgiven. :)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Haha, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As lulu has suggested in the comment, the answer is no.

**proof**

Evidently, if $f$ is constant, it cannot satisfy the requirement.

Suppose $f$ is nonconstant. Then $f$ must be nonconstant on some compact subset $[a, b]$, $a, b\in \mathbb R$.

Since $f$ is continuous, it achieves its minimum and maximum on $[a, b]$. Denote the minimum as $m$ and the maximum as $n$, then $f$ achieves every value in $[m, n]$ at least once, again by continuity of $f$.

Since there are uncountably many irrational numbers in $[m, n]$ and the set of all rational numbers is countable, it cannot be the case that $f(x)$ is irrational if and only if $x$ is rational. $\square$

Many thanks to lulu for the hint!