# $f(\mathbb{Q}) \subset \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}) \subset \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: continuity

Continuous function $f$ such that $f(\mathbb{Q}) \subset \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}) \subset \mathbb{Q}$

(I know this question has already been asked and answered but there the idea used was the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. Here I want to try another idea- as described in my outline Reference: [Continuous function that take irrationals to rationals and vice-versa.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367856/continuous-function-that-take-irrationals-to-rationals-and-vice-versa).)

My attempt: I choose $m = 3$ and $c \in \mathbb{Q}$ and draw a family of lines $L_c: y = 3x + c$. If such a $f(x)$ exists and **if** $f(x) \cap L_c \neq \emptyset$, then they intersect at $x$.

Two cases follow:

Case I: $x$ is rational.

Then $y = 3x + c \in \mathbb{Q}$ a contradiction to the definition of $f(x)$.

Case II: $x$ is irrational.

Then $y = 3x + c \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$ again a contradiction to the definition of $f(x)$.

So my plan is draw the family $L_c$ on $\mathbb{R^2}$ and show that $f(x)$ intersection atleast one of the line

Now if I don't want $f(x)$ to intersect $L_c$, then I have the following inequality $$3x + c < f(x) < 3x + c + \frac{1}{n}.$$

I keep increasing $n$ and hence reach the conclusion that no such $f(x)$ exists. The problem with my proof is I want my conclusion to be $f(x) = 3x + c, c\in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$. Can someone fix my proof.

Comment: $f(x)\cap L_c$ doesn't make sense.  Are you thinking of $\Gamma(f)\cap L_c$ or something else?

Comment: @user10354138 I mean the intersection points of $L_c$ and $f(x)$.